# Issue with multiple forms

Tags: php, forms

I have two forms on my page. One is in the footer which I cannot change. The second is in my main page. Confused? I hope not.

When I open the style-demo page (link below) you can see that the information belonging in the Footer form is partially entered into the comment form on the page.

The Form in the footer works correctly however the comment section does not.
Any help to have both work would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Here are my links

http://richardtamm.com/includes/footer.php
http://richardtamm.com/style-demo.php

Here is the code

Footer

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="footer" class="clear">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <div id="about_us" class="border">
        <h2>About R. Tamm</h2>
        <p>Richard Tamm is an avid photographer and writer. Richard was born in the         state of Michigan and currently lives in the state of Indiana. He is married with 4 wonderful children who love to call him daddy. </p>
        <p>When not writing or taking photographs Richard enjoys watching movies and spending quality time with his family.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="contact" class="clear">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <div class="fl_left">
          <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
            <label for="comments">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" value="submit"><span>Submit</span></button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="fl_right">
          <address>
          <strong class="title">Company Name</strong><br>
          Richard Tamm<br>
          EYE-TO-IMAGE<br>
          Jasonville, Indiana<br>
          47438
          </address>
          <ul>
            <!--<li><strong class="title">Tel:</strong><br>
              xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</li>
            <li><strong class="title">Fax:</strong><br>
              xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</li>-->
            <li><strong class="title">Email:</strong><br>
              <a href="mailto:<?php echo $emailaddress; ?>"><?php echo $emailaddress; ?></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div class="fl_right">
      <div id="tabcontainer" class="border">
        <ul id="tabnav">
          <li><a href="#tabs-1">From The Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tabs-2">Latest Tweets</a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="#tabs-3">Link Share</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" class="tabcontainer">
          <script src="layout/scripts/blogfeed.setup.js"></script>
          <script src="http://widget.feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"></script>
          <div style="font-size:10px; text-align:right;"><a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">RSS widget</a></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ########### -->
        <div id="tabs-2" class="tabcontainer">
          <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/rltamm" data-widget-id="435882309061865472">Tweets by @rltamm</a>
          <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
        </div>
        <!-- ########### -->
        <div id="tabs-3" class="tabcontainer">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>Keep Up To Date</h2>
      <ul class="socialize">
        <li><span>Facebook:</span> <a href="http://facebook.com/rltamm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.facebook.com/rltamm</a></li>
        <li class="last"><span>Twitter:</span> <a href="http://twitter.com/rltamm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.twitter.com/rltamm</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="backtotop"><a href="#top" class="topOfPage">To The Top <span class="icon-arrow-up"></span></a></div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="copyright" class="clear">
    <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2011 - 2014 All Rights Reserved - <a href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>"><?php echo $sitename; ?></a></p>
    <p class="fl_right">Website by <?php echo $sitename; ?> &amp; <a target="_blank" href="http://www.os-templates.com/" title="Free Website Templates">OS Templates</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.defaultvalue.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#first_name, #last_name, #email, #comments").defaultvalue("First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Message");
    $('a.topOfPage').click(function () {
        $.scrollTo(0, 1200);
        return false;
    });
    $("#tabcontainer").tabs({
        event: "click"
    });
});
</script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery-prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery-prettyPhoto-setup.js"></script>
```

Main Page

```
<?php
$titletag = 'Bookshelf - Page 1';
$metdescr = 'This is the SEO description - not too long not to short used in Google search results';
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/includes/header.php');
?>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper col4">
  <div id="container" class="clear">
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <?php include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/includes/shout.php'); ?>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div id="content">
      <h1>&lt;h1&gt; to &lt;h6&gt; - Headline Colour and Size Are All The Same</h1>
      <img class="imgr" src="images/demo/imgr.gif" alt="" width="125" height="125" />
      <p>Aliquatjusto quisque nam consequat doloreet vest orna partur scetur portortis nam. Metadipiscing eget facilis elit sagittis felisi eger id justo maurisus convallicitur.</p>
      <p>Dapiensociis <a href="#">temper donec auctortortis cumsan</a> et curabitur condis lorem loborttis leo. Ipsumcommodo libero nunc at in velis tincidunt pellentum tincidunt vel lorem.</p>
      <img class="imgl" src="images/demo/imgl.gif" alt="" width="125" height="125" />
      <p>This is a W3C compliant free website template from <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/" title="Free Website Templates">OS Templates</a>. This template is distributed using a <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">Website Template Licence</a>.</p>
      <p>You can use and modify the template for both personal and commercial use. You must keep all copyright information and credit links in the template and associated files. For more CSS templates visit <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/">Free Website Templates</a>.</p>
      <p>Portortornec condimenterdum eget consectetuer condis consequam pretium pellus sed mauris enim. Puruselit mauris nulla hendimentesque elit semper nam a sapien urna sempus.</p>
      <h2>Table(s)</h2>
      <table summary="Summary Here" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="light">
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
            <td>Value 3</td>
            <td>Value 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dark">
            <td>Value 5</td>
            <td>Value 6</td>
            <td>Value 7</td>
            <td>Value 8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="light">
            <td>Value 9</td>
            <td>Value 10</td>
            <td>Value 11</td>
            <td>Value 12</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dark">
            <td>Value 13</td>
            <td>Value 14</td>
            <td>Value 15</td>
            <td>Value 16</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="comments">
        <h2>Comments</h2>
        <ul class="commentlist">
          <li class="comment_odd">
            <div class="author"><img class="avatar" src="images/demo/avatar.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="" /><span class="name"><a href="#">A Name</a></span> <span class="wrote">wrote:</span></div>
            <div class="submitdate"><a href="#">August 4, 2009 at 8:35 am</a></div>
            <p>This is an example of a comment made on a post. You can either edit the comment, delete the comment or reply to the comment. Use this as a place to respond to the post or to share what you are thinking.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="comment_even">
            <div class="author"><img class="avatar" src="images/demo/avatar.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="" /><span class="name"><a href="#">A Name</a></span> <span class="wrote">wrote:</span></div>
            <div class="submitdate"><a href="#">August 4, 2009 at 8:35 am</a></div>
            <p>This is an example of a comment made on a post. You can either edit the comment, delete the comment or reply to the comment. Use this as a place to respond to the post or to share what you are thinking.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="comment_odd">
            <div class="author"><img class="avatar" src="images/demo/avatar.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="" /><span class="name"><a href="#">A Name</a></span> <span class="wrote">wrote:</span></div>
            <div class="submitdate"><a href="#">August 4, 2009 at 8:35 am</a></div>
            <p>This is an example of a comment made on a post. You can either edit the comment, delete the comment or reply to the comment. Use this as a place to respond to the post or to share what you are thinking.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Write A Comment</h2>
      <div id="respond">
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="22" />
            <label for="name"><small>Name (required)</small></label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="22" />
            <label for="email"><small>Mail (required)</small></label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10"></textarea>
            <label for="comment" style="display:none;"><small>Comment (required)</small></label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form" />
            &nbsp;
            <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" tabindex="5" value="Reset Form" />
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column">
      <div class="subnav">
        <h2>Secondary Navigation</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Open Source Templates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Free CSS Templates</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Free XHTML Templates</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Free Website Templates</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Open Source Layouts</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Open Source Software</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Open Source Webdesign</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Open Source Downloads</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Open Source Website</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Open Source Themes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
        <h2 class="title"><img src="images/demo/60x60.gif" alt="" />Nullamlacus dui ipsum conseque</h2>
        <p>Nullamlacus dui ipsum conseque loborttis non euisque morbi penas dapibulum orna. Urnaultrices quis curabitur phasellentesque.</p>
        <p class="readmore"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div id="featured">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h2>Indonectetus facilis</h2>
            <p class="imgholder"><img src="images/demo/240x90.gif" alt="" /></p>
            <p>Nullamlacus dui ipsum conseque loborttis non euisque morbi penas dapibulum orna. Urnaultrices quis curabitur phasellentesque congue magnis vestibulum quismodo nulla et feugiat. Adipisciniapellentum leo ut consequam ris felit elit id nibh sociis malesuada.</p>
            <p class="readmore"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p>Nuncsed sed conseque a at quismodo tris mauristibus sed habiturpiscinia sed.</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
          <li>Etiam vel sapien et</li>
          <li><a href="#">Etiam vel sapien et</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Nuncsed sed conseque a at quismodo tris mauristibus sed habiturpiscinia sed. Condimentumsantincidunt dui mattis magna intesque purus orci augue lor nibh.</p>
        <p class="readmore"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<?php include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/includes/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main page, the form is defined as `<form action="#" method="post">`. For the action, you need to put the PHP file you're calling. `#` doesn't make sense. Look at your other declaration:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
```

This makes sense. It's telling HTML to send to send_form_email.php the information through POST.

Comment: OK.. I dont have a page to call.. :( I thought the script at bottom of footer page was to make the comment section work.

Comment: @user1995348 If you're not invoking any specific PHP file, what do you expect it to do? It will just be a plain form.

Comment: Any Idea of a simple script to make the comments post to the page?

Comment: My apologizes. I am not familiar with this at all..I am working on it all as trial and error..

Comment: @user1995348 Do you know any PHP? Do you have a MySQL database?

Comment: I know very little php myself. I am decent with following instructions and so have a MySQL database yes. I can create anything needed in MySQL for a database.

Comment: alternatively you could use `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` to send POST data to the current/main page

Comment: @JohannesTrümpelmann do you have more detail on how that would work? And would it stop the conflict between footer and comment sections? Would i be able to direct it correctly to the <div> section where the comments are to be placed?

Comment: you can use anchors in form tags like `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>#comments"`, but you still had to use a database to save the comments.
As you don't know much about PHP, you should inform yourself about SQL injections and other vulnerabilities and directly start using prepared statements or PHP data objects for your SQL queries.

Comment: @JohannesTrümpelmann any ideas where i could find mentioned "prepared statements or PHP data bojects?"

Comment: Prepared statements: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

please note that you need the MySQL Native Drivers installed to use prepared statements. If you don't, you can simply install them on Linux using `apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`